# IE is not showing updated IMG SRC change done in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

ISSUE: IE version 7 and 8 is not showing updated IMG SRC change done in JavaScript

You can see what I mean if you go to the URL below, and on the left under (3) I want a different liner, you choose one of the swatches; lets say you choose "Asahi Chartreuse". Notice nothing happens to the preview on the left. BUT then if you go ahead and choose another swatch, you will see the preview on the left shift to show Asahi Chartreuse. So it is one behind. This is why I believe it is a "refresh" issue. It works in Chrome just fine.

In IE: Notice if you click on some other control, the refresh happens.

You can see the code here: https://www.casemodo.com/test.asp

WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:

I've tried adding headers to say "no-cache".

I've tried adding "?" and random number after the png file name.

I've tried setting focus() to the image after changing the src.

I've tried, after changing src, telling the style.display to be hidden and then visible.

I've tried creating a hidden (and not hidden) text input box on the page and then setting focus() to it after changing img src.

I've tried setting window.focus().

I've tried (as you see now) setting an alert after changing the src.

GUESS: What it looks like now is the JavaScript engine just pauses after I set that src UNTIL you manually click (focus) somewhere else on the screen. So it never even gets to all of those scripts I've tried above.

Comment: Please show us your code (html+js)

Answer (score 8):

Set the src attribute to null, then set it to your new url:

in jquery:

```
var myImg = $('#myImg');
myImg.attr('src', null);
myImg.attr('src', newUrl);
```

in straight js:

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
myImg.src = null;
myImg.src = newUrl
```

This worked for me - it was driving me mad!

Comment: It works just once :( Then IE use cache img even when i use url like http://example.com/img/my.jpg?rand=231123

Answer (score 2):

Try to use onclick instead of onchange. The latter doesnt work well with some form elements in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar IE issues solved with a seemingly bizarre reassignment of innerHTML.  Suppose "container" is a variable referencing the parentNode of the img. Try "container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML".  This triggers a re-rendering and may bring the errant img to life.

Answer (score 1):

Comments on the question:

- Please include a code snippet in the question.
- Was the javascript in an onchange event, or where?
- If the client browser is Google Chrome, does it work?
  (Sounds like yet-another-IE-image-src-bug.)
- The demonstration page you linked to has been changed since this question was posted;
  as I write this, clicking on a swatch causes submit which causes load of a different page.

A suggestion:

- Use `setTimeout`, so that the actual change occurs when the timeout event fires, instead of in the original GUI event thread.
  For example, if the original javascript was

  ```
  SomeFunction();
  ```

  change this to

  ```
  setTimeout(SomeFunction, 10);
  ```

  (where `image.src = newURL;` is done inside `SomeFunction`)

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably no longer relevant but we ran into the same issue today when we checked backward compatibility for one of our libraries.

The only thing that worked for us was to replace the image element by itself before changing the value for the `src` attribute:

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
myImg.parentNode.replaceChild(myImg, myImg);
myImg.src = newUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a Lazy Loading implementation, and got to a similar problem. For some reason, after changing the *data-srcset* attributes to *srcset* in code, even with the other approaches described on this page, the elements still didn't seem to get the new attributes values. After some research, I got to this [page on github](https://github.com/digitoimistodude/dude/commit/0519dc5cf31c9a47c6b66a02818208ca64453082), about a bug fix on a lazy loading plugin. It gave me the idea to, instead of using the replace option described here, or the `your_element.src=null` approach, to use something like this:

```
your_element.setAttribute("src", your_element.getAttribute("data-srcset"));
```

And it ended up working for me.